# Advanced combinatorics question for R

Tags: r, combinatorics

I have 2 groups with 3 observations each.

Group 1: a=1, b=3, and c=2

Group 2: d=0, e=1, and f=0

I would like to understand which group has the higher values, but cannot use a t-test (neither non-parametric nor dependent t-tests can resolve the special dependency I have in my data).

A solution is to now create all possible combinations of observations. In addition to our data order abc-def, we create abd-cef, abe-cdf, abf-cde, etc. We want all possible permutations, but we don't count within group order differences (abc-def is not different from abc-edf and should be considered one permutation, because the same items belong to the same group).

We create a distribution of group differences across all permutations, and can find out whether our data is within the 2.5% on both ends to see whether the difference is significant on a 5% level.

How would I go about this in R? (I have many more observations but once this example code is setup I could adapt).

Comment: Although the referenced *question* is not a duplicate of this one, [@Gung's reply there](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/137188/919) completely answers this question, right down to working `R` code.

Answer (score 1):

Permutation tests are actually implemented in R in [coin](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i08/) package so I would recommend checking it first before coding things by hand. However, if you want to code your function then you could use [combn](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html) function from `utils` library (available by default). `combn` generates all possible combinations of elements in given input variable (vector, matrix etc.). Notice however that the number of possible combinations depends on the number of distinct values in your variables and could be possibly *huge*, so this could be possibly very time-inefficient method.