# How to calculate probability of observing a value given a permutation distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, random-variable, permutation-test

I have a single observation with value $x = 0.5$ that comes out from a complicated computational process. I would like to know what is the probability to observe such value by chance.

To attempt to answer the question, I have ran the computational process with random input values for few thousand times. I get a distribution that is about normal, has mean very close to zero, and a standard deviation around 0.09.

Intuitively, it looks like the chance of observing 0.5 by chance is very little. However, how do I turn this into an actual statistical test?

Comment: I have posted code showing how to conduct permutation tests. A simple working example is at the end of the answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/137467, for instance. A general description of permutation tests, along with a generic description of how to code them, appears in the survey at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/104746.

Answer (score 4):

This is quite straightforward, there is no need to infer a distribution under the Null Hypothesis. Your p-value is just the number of times $x_{permuted}$ get superior or equal to $0.5$, divided by the number of permutations made.
This fits the definition of the p-value: *"If H0 is true and a new sample is drawn, what is the probability to get at least such extreme results ?"*

Maybe you mixed things up with the Bootstrap procedure which is generally done to estimate the "*real*" distribution of your statistic of interest.

I don't say your approach is completely wrong, if your distribution looks like normal, you could eventually do a `z-test`, and it should give a quite reliable p-value. But I think the spirit of the permutation test is just to count how often you indeed get equal or more extreme results because you have a direct access to it, whatever the real distribution of $x_{permuted}$ is.

For the sake of the comparison it would be interesting that you give how often $x_{permuted}$ get superior or equal to $0.5$ in your data set, we could compare it with what would give a 1-tailed z-test.