# What is the probability of one event being likelier than another

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have two independent experiments

In experiment 1, I perform n1 trials, and I have s1 successes.

In experiment 2, I perform n2 trials, and I have s2 successes.

How do I find out (without conducting more trials) whether it's significantly more likely that a trial in experiment 1 succeeds than that a trial in experiment 2 succeeds?

Comment: As a self-comment, right now I'm primarily interested in the answer to the question, but answers that also help me find how I can solve these kinds of problems are greatly appreciated. Not sure if that means I should tag this as self-study or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting $p_1 = \frac{s_1}{n_1}, p_2 = \frac{s_2}{n_2}$ [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/113607/106369) is exactly what you need.

For more tests like this you can take a look at the wikipedia page of [Statistical hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing).

Answer (score 0):

You compute the difference between the two estimated proportions and test that the true difference is statistically greater than 0.