# A/B Testing on Aggregate Measures

Tags: hypothesis-testing, experiment-design, aggregation

Suppose we have built a new version of the "Recommended" page of our media website (e.g. Netflix) and are running a test to evaluate its effectiveness.

We can collect data in the following schema:

`username {string} | test_cell {"control" or "enabled"} | rec_page_streaming_minutes {integer} | total_streaming_minutes {integer}, stream_1_minute {boolean}, | stream_1_hour {boolean}`

A few key metrics we are interested in measuring:

- What % of total time spent streaming content on the website is discovered from the Recommended page?

  - `SUM(rec_page_streaming_minutes) / SUM(total_streaming_minutes)`
- What % of users stream content discovered on the Recommended page for at least 1 minute?

  - `SUM(IF stream_1_minute THEN 1 ELSE 0) / COUNT(*)`
- What % of users who stream content from the Recommended Page for at least 1 minute continue streaming for at least 1 hour?

  - `SUM(IF stream_1_hour THEN 1 ELSE 0) / SUM(IF stream_1_minute THEN 1 ELSE 0)`

How would we go about evaluating these metrics for statistical significance (i.e. to determine if the enabled version of the page significantly increases any of them)? Can we build confidence intervals for these, or do need to modify our metrics?

Answer (score 1):

It seems in your second and third scenarios, you have proportions of visitors to each site who meet a particular criterion ('Success'). You want to see whether the two observed binomial proportions $\hat p_1$ and $\hat p_2$ are significantly different. Formally, you would test $H_0: p_1 = p_2$ against $H_a: p_1 \ne p_2.$

The [NIST handbook](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/binotest.htm) describes one such test, which relies on a normal approximation of the difference. I assume your sample sizes in this application would be large enough to get good results from this test. 
A discussion of this test can be found [on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113602/test-if-two-binomial-distributions-are-statistically-different-from-each-other).

**Formula:** Suppose we $X_1$ successes among $n_1$ visitors to the first type of page. If we estimate $p_1$ by $\hat p_1 = X_1/n_1.$ 
Similar for the second type of page, we estimate $p_2$ by $\hat p_2 = X_2/n_2.$  Then because the null hypothesis states that $p_1 = p_2 = p,$ we estimate $p$ by $\hat p = (X_1 + X_2)/(n_1 + n_2).$
Then the test statistic is
$$Z = \frac{\hat p_1 - \hat p_2}{\sqrt{\hat p(1-\hat p)(1/n_1 + 1/n_2)}}$$

Because $Z$ is approximately normal under $H_0,$ we reject $H_0,$ if $|Z|> 1.96.$

*Exapmple:* Suppose $ X_1 = 503,  n_1 = 2500; 
X_2 = 587,  n_2 = 2400.$ Then $Z = -3.65$ and we reject $H_0.$
Under $H_0,$ the probability of a more extreme result (in either direction) is the P-value $0.0003.%

Using  R as a calculator:

```
x1 = 503;  n1 = 2500;  x2 = 587;  n2 = 2400
p1.hat = x1/n1;  p2.hat = x2/n2
p.hat = (x1+x2)/(n1 + n2)
se = sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)*(1/n1 + 1/n2))
z = (p1.hat - p2.hat)/se;  z
[1] -3.650235
p.val = 2*pnorm(z)
[1] 0.0002620003
```

This test is implemented in R, using the chi-squared distribution with one degree of freedom and a continuity correction also rejects $H_0.$ [The square of a standard normal random variable is a chi-squared random variable with one degree of freedom.]

```
prop.test(c(503,587), c(2500,2400))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(503, 587) out of c(2500, 2400)
X-squared = 13.075, df = 1, p-value = 0.0002993
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.06708736 -0.01967930
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.2012000 0.2445833
```

Using the parameter `cor=F` in the procedure `prop.test` gets rid
of the continuity correction, and gives essentially the same P-value as my direct computation from the formula for $Z.$

```
prop.test(c(503,587), c(2500,2400), cor=F)$p.val
[1] 0.0002620003
```

*Note:* In your first scenario, I suppose your data will consist
of two lists of proportions of times. If sample sizes are large
I suppose you could compare the two samples using a two-sample t test. I would have to know your sample sizes and see your data to give a better informed opinion.