# Check if multiple percentage are significant

Tags: t-test, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test, percentage, exact-test

I have 3 measurements of a very skew distribution, depending on three different technique. In general, I can do thousands of test and the result is either "fail" or "success", being the "fail" far more common than the success (more than 99% of fails). So, I have these data:

Random:    Ntests = 20894   Nsuccess = 26    percentage = 0.124438%
Normal:    Ntests = 229848  Nsuccess = 334   percentage = 0.145313%
Optimized: Ntests = 20272   Nsuccess = 44    percentage = 0.217048%

How can I check that the differences in the percentages are significant?

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate statistical test is [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher's_exact_test). Given your large numbers, you will need to use simulation to obtain $p$ values. In R, you can do this as follows:

```
> TT <- rbind(c(20894-26,229848-334,20272-44),c(26,334,44))
> fisher.test(TT,simulate.p.value=TRUE,B=10000)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data with simulated p-value (based on 10000 replicates)

data:  TT
p-value = 0.0282
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

See [Test if two binomial distributions are statistically different from each other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/113602/1352), in particular [David Makovoz' answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/127147/1352), which points to Fisher's test, which works for more than two groups.