# power of one sided z test for proportions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, statistical-power

My question is an extension of [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113602/test-if-two-binomial-distributions-are-statistically-different-from-each-other) and is about the power of a one-sided z-test for proportion differences: I have samples from two Binomially distributed trials $X_A\sim\text{Bin}(n_A, p_A), X_B\sim\text{Bin}(n_B, p_B)$, i.e. I know the outcomes $x_A, x_B$ as well as the sample sizes $n_A, n_B$. I would like to test whether $X_B$ exhibits a significantly higher success rate than $X_A$ using the MLE estimates $\hat{p}_A=\frac{x_A}{n_A}, \hat{p}_B=\frac{x_B}{n_B}$ as proxies for the success rates:
$$
H_0: \hat{p}_A\geq \hat{p}_B\\
H_1: \hat{p}_A < \hat{p}_B
$$

The z-statistic is given by
$$
z = \frac{\hat{p}_B-\hat{p}_A}{\sqrt{\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})(n_A^{-1}+n_B^{-1})}}
$$
where $\hat{p}=\frac{n_A\hat{p}_A+n_B\hat{p}_B}{n_A+n_B}$.

According to [this document](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/PASS/Tests_for_One_Proportion.pdf) (page 6) the power of the z-test is given by
$$
P(\text{reject H}_0|\ \text{H}_0\text{ false})=1-\Phi\left[\frac{\sqrt{n}(p_A-p_B)+z_{\alpha}\sqrt{p_A(1-p_A)}}{\sqrt{p_B(1-p_B)}}\right]
$$
I am not quite sure how to arrive at this result.

Comment: You misquote the document.  Your formulas for power make no sense, because power is a function of the *true* probabilities and sample sizes; it cannot under any circumstances also depend on the *estimated* probabilities.

Comment: @whuber ok that's fair. But let's say we knew the true success probabilities, I still don't understand how to arrive at that power formula