# Statistical Significance of survey

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, z-test

I recently conducted a survey comparing the generated responses of 2 chatbots. Each participant was asked to complete two tasks:

1. Select a generated response as "best" between 2 generated responses.
2. Rate a generated response with a number from 1 (very bad) to 5 (excellent). This task was done 2 times one for each chatbot.

Each participant completed the survey once.

So according to the 1st task, I gathered $N=308$ samples, from which $N_1=170$ prefer the 1st response while the remaining $N_2=138$ the 2nd one. Consequently, I have a ~55% win rate of the 1st chatbot.

According to the 2nd task, I gathered $N=308$ samples for each chatbot. The average rating of the 1st chatbot is $μ_1=3.5$ and of the 2nd is $μ_2=3.37$.

I would like to test the statistical significance of the above results. (For the 2nd task I thought that using an independent one-tailed t-test was a good idea but the normality criterion is violated).
Which test method I should use for each task?

Answer (score 0):

(1) I assume you want to test $H_0: p=.5$ vs. $H_a: p>.5.$ Under $H_0,$
the number of successes is $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=408, p=.5),$ and the
P-value of this right-tailed test is
$$P(X \ge 178\,|\,H_0) = 1 - P(X\le 177\,|\,H_0) = 0.0037 < 0.05$$,
by an exact binomial computation in R (below), so you will reject $H_0$
in favor of $H_a$ at the 5% level (also at the 0.5% level).

```
1 - pbinom(177, 308, .5)
[1] 0.003652809
```

Your estimate $\hat p \approx 0.55$ of the success probability $p$ is incorrect,
it should be $\hat p = 178/308 =  0.578.$

Unless you are regularly using technology such as a statistical calculator
or statistical computer software, in your course, I don't suppose you are expected to compute
the exact binomial P-value.

Perhaps, you are supposed to get a normal approximation
to $X$ by using $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma),$ where (under $H_0)$ $\mu = 308(.5) = 154,
\sigma = \sqrt{208(.25)} = 8.775).$ Then you can find
$P(X \ge 177.5\,|\,H_0) \approx 0.0037$ by
standardizing and using printed tables of the standard normal CDF.
I will leave the details of that to you.

(2) You can do a two-sample t test if you have sample sizes, means, and standard deviations---along with the knowledge that your observations are a random sample from a (nearly)
normal distribution. (The correct notation for the two sample means would be
$\bar X_1 = 3.5; \bar X_2 = 3.37,$ and you are missing the required standard deviations.)

However, you say the normality criterion is violated, so you
would need to do a nonparametric test to compare the centers of the two distributions.
If the samples are of about the same shape, you could use a two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test. And for that you would need to have the $n_1 = n_2 = 308$ observation from
the two samples.

Suppose I have samples `x1` and `x2` (both of size 308) in R, with descriptive statistics as below:

```
summary(x1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.6899  2.5553  3.2400  3.5036  4.1538  8.0909 
summary(x2)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.191   2.626   3.436   3.580   4.357   9.066
```

Boxplots of the two samples are shown below. They are noticeably right-skewed. Enough so, that I would not want compare them with a t test. (Also, both are rejected as normal by Shapiro-Wilk tests, with very small P-values;  not shown.) More important, the medians (vertical bars within boxes) do not differ by much compared with the large variability of the two samples.

```
boxplot(x1, x2, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

Because shapes of the samples are very similar, it seems appropriate to use a 2-sample Wilcoxon test to see if one sample is significantly shifted relative to the other.
(Roughly speaking, we might say we are comparing the two sample medians for significance.) The P-value is well above 0.05, so the null hypothesis of equal medians
is not rejected.

```
wilcox.test(x1, x2)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  x1 and x2
W = 45006, p-value = 0.2721
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Of course, these are my fake data sampled in R. It is possible that two-sample Wilcoxon test for your real data, if you have them available, would show a significant difference (on account of considerably less variability).

Comment: Excuse me for providing wrong value for $N_1$. I have edited my question. The correct value is $N_1=170$ as $N_1+N_2=N$

Comment: As it concerns the 1st task, I wonder if using a method like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113602/test-if-two-binomial-distributions-are-statistically-different-from-each-other) is wrong.
According to the binomial test I calculated the p-value in Python like this:
`print(stats.binom_test(170,308,p=0.5,alternative='greater'))
0.03858027511878762`
So the null hypothesis is rejected. Does that mean that my estimated $\hat{p}$ is statistically significant with $a=0.05$?
As it concerns the 2nd task, can I use the Mann-Witney U test?