# How do I perform a statistical test to see if the difference between my 2 observations is significant or not?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have 2 discrete data sets (responses given my 2 different sets of people) of size 6000. Let's say that each data point is either 1 or 0.

| S.No. | Dataset 1 | Dataset 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 |
| .... | ..... | ..... |
| .... | ..... | ..... |
| 6000 | 0 | 1 |

I have calculated the error rate (by comparing these answers against true answers). The error rate in dataset 1 is 84% and the error rate in dataset 2 is 89%. I want to understand if the difference between these 2 error rates is significant or not. How do I do it? Please help me with this.

Comment: What is an "error" here?

Comment: Error rate is simply the mis match rate between observed answers in these 2 populations and the actual answers.

Comment: Error rates of $80\%+$ are not good in a binary prediction.  Does $1$ mean correct or wrong or something else? And $0$ wrong or correct or something else?

Comment: It was just an example. It could be as low as 2 or 3%. My question is more around on how to decide if there is a significant difference between 2 sets of observations.

Comment: Is your question different from this? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113602/test-if-two-binomial-distributions-are-statistically-different-from-each-other